# How to redirect to login page if JWT is not valid, using Express with API

Tags: express, axios, jwt, frontend

I've built an Express app that contains an API and a front end. By using Axios the front end can request data (e.g. a user-object or a todo-object) from the API, which will validate the offered JWT with its middleware. If the `jwt.verify()` errs, the protected routes won't fire. This all works fine.

**My question is: how do I set up the front end such that any page-request will redirect to a login page if the browser-stored JWT is not valid (excluding the login and register pages, to prevent circular redirection)?** Do I have to preface every `.ejs`-file with an `Axios.post()` that sends the browser-stored JWT for verification, or is there a best practice that I am missing?

My goal, when an invalid JWT is offered, is to have the API routes return a json-object (e.g. `{ err: "invalid token offered" }`), and to have all the front end routes redirect the user to the login page.

Some sample code below.

**server.js**

```
// API Routes
app.use('/api/todos', CheckToken, APITodosRouter)
app.use('/api/auth', APIAuthRouter)

// Front-end Routes
app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/todos', todosRouter)
app.use('/auth', authRouter)
```

**todos.ejs** (This works fine)

```
// get todos from db

let todosData
const getTodos = async () => {
  let response = await axios.get('/api/todos/all', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.access_token}`
    }
  })
  if (!response) return console.log({ msg: "no response received."})
  if (!response.data) return console.log({ msg: "no data received."})
  if (!response.data.payload) return console.log({ msg: "no todos found."})
  todosData = response.data.payload
}


// boot page

;(async () => {
  await getTodos()
  renderTodos()  // a function that reads todosData updates the DOM accordingly
})()
```

**checkToken.js** (Middleware)

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const checkToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const ah = req.headers.authorization
    const token = ah && ah.split(' ')[1]
    if (!token) return res.json({ msg: "No token offered."})
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ msg: "Invalid token offered."})
        req.user = user
        next()
    })
}

module.exports = checkToken
```

Comment: Instead of returning **res.json({ msg: "Invalid token offered."})** from your middleware. Can't you simply redirect the user to the login page? Like this,  **res.redirect('/login')**

Comment: 1. If I do, I can't protect the app's '/' route, because '/login' will be a circular redirect. Will I have to protect every single route *except* '/' if I do this? 
2. I want failed requests to the API with Postman or Axios to receive JSONs

Comment: 1. I don't understand why your /login will be a circular redirect. It should be a public route and a user should not be allowed to navigate to private routes without having a JWT token. 2. You can pass the data with res.redirect as well by using the req.session.context.